# Set default bootstrap theme mode for print mode

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

Bootstrap allows theming via setting the `data-bs-theme` attribute on the body or parent element. All this works well, but we found that light mode is the best for printing. Rather than write a whole set of styles for printing in dark mode, I wrote some stopgap JavaScript code that switches to light mode before any print operation and then switches back to the previous mode after the user begins printing.

This works, but it's not the best user experience. In Chrome in particular the switch between light and dark modes while the print modal is open can be jarring.

Is there a better approach here between using JavaScript to catch the event and writing a whole new set of CSS just for printing in dark mode?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. The way I solved it was using the below code when the page loads. I first attempted to listen for print requests (I assume similar to what you did), but I discovered through experimentation that the "preferred-color-scheme" event fires with value "light" when one attempts to print. Plus, I need to monitor this one, anyway, to catch user-initiated color scheme changes.

I'd love to know if this works for you, too. I tested on Edge, Chrome, Firefox, and a few others. I would like to know if another browser has different behavior that causes this to fail.

```js
(() =>
{
    // Determine the browser's preferred theme
    function GetPreferredTheme()
    {
        // Assume light mode by default
        var selected_theme = "light";

        // Select the "dark" theme if the browser prefers it
        if (window.matchMedia &&
            window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches)
        {
            selected_theme = "dark";
        }

        return selected_theme;
    };

    // Set the theme as specified or default to browser's preferred theme
    function SetTheme(theme = "")
    {
        if (theme.length == 0)
        {
            theme = GetPreferredTheme();
        }
        document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-bs-theme", theme);
    };

    // Scheme listener where event matches if dark theme is selected
    function SchemeListener(event)
    {
        event.matches ? SetTheme("dark") : SetTheme("light");
    };


    // If window.matchMedia is supported, install listener to switch themes
    if (window.matchMedia)
    {
        // Install listeners to switch when user changes settings
        var scheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
        if (scheme)
        {
            scheme.addEventListener("change", SchemeListener);
        }
    }

    // Display using the browser's preferred theme
    SetTheme();
})();
```